# creating an array for a snapping function with ActionScript 3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, puzzle

I created a puzzle where you can drag and drop 16 pieces. I used an array so that the code doesn't get too big. Now I want to add an function where each puzzle piece snaps into right place once you get near the destination.

My problem is that I don't know how to create an array which can achieve my goal. I tried the following(without an array but that creates too much code if I do it with all 16 puzzle pieces):

```
if(target1_mc.hitTestObject(piece1_mc.tar1_mc))
        {
            piece1_mc.x = 207,15;
            piece1_mc.y = 119,25;
        }
```

Code:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    var puzzleArr:Array = new Array (piece1_mc, piece2_mc, piece3_mc, piece4_mc,
piece5_mc, piece6_mc, piece7_mc, piece8_mc, 
piece9_mc, piece10_mc, 
piece11_mc, piece12_mc, piece13_mc, piece14_mc, piece15_mc, piece16_mc);


for (var i:uint =0; i < puzzleArr.length; i++) {
 puzzleArr[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
 puzzleArr[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);
}


function drag(event:MouseEvent):void {
 event.currentTarget.startDrag();
}


function drop(event:MouseEvent):void {
 event.currentTarget.stopDrag();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a few ways to accomplish this.     The easiest, is to add a dynamic property to your pieces that stores the target (correct location object) for the piece.

```
var puzzleArr:Array = []; //you don't really even need the array in my example
var tmpPiece:MovieClip; //this stores the current dragging piece, and I also reuse it in the loop below 

//I don't like typing a lot, so let's use a loop for all 16 pieces and their targets
for(var i:int=1;i<=16;i++){
    tmpPiece = this["piece" + i + "_mc"]; //get a reference to piece whose number matches i

    if(!tmpPiece){
        trace("Sorry - there is no piece called: 'piece" + i + "_mc'");
        continue;
    }

    //give the piece a dynamic property that is a reference to it's target spot
    tmpPiece.targetTile = this["target" + i + "_mc"];

    if(!tmpPiece.targetTile){
        trace("Sorry - there is no target called: 'target" + i + "_mc'");
        continue;
    }

    tmpPiece.tar_mc = tmpPiece["tar" + i + "_mc"]; //it would be better to just take the number out of each pieces tar_mc child object making this line uneccessary

    //track where the piece is placed
    tmpPiece.startingPos = new Point(tmpPiece.x, tmpPiece.y);

    //only add the mouse down listener to the piece (not mouse up)
    tmpPiece.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);

    //if still using the array, add the piece to the array
    puzzleArr.push(tmpPiece);
}
```

Next, add a mouse move listener only while dragging

```
function drag(event:MouseEvent):void {
    tmpPiece = event.currentTarget as MovieClip; //assign the dragging object to the tmpPiece var


    tmpPiece.startDrag();

    //add a mouse move listener so you can check if snapping is needed
    tmpPiece.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, moving);

    //add the mouse up listener to the stage - this is good because if you drag fast, the mouse can leave the object your dragging, and if you release the mouse then it won't trigger a mouse up on the dragging object
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);
}

function drop(event:MouseEvent):void {
    //stop all dragging
    this.stopDrag();

    if(tmpPiece){
        //remove the mouse move listener
        tmpPiece.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, moving);

        //ensure a snap at the end of the drag
        if(!checkSnapping()){
           //if not snapped, reset it's position
           tmpPiece.x = tmpPiece.startingPos.x;
           tmpPiece.y = tmpPiece.startingPos.y;
        } 
    }

    //remove the mouse up listener
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);
}
```

Now lets do the snapping in the mouse move handler:

```
function moving(e:MouseEvent = null):void {
    checkSnapping();
}

//return true if snapped
function checkSnapping():Boolean {
    if(tmpPiece && tmpPiece.tar_mc.hitTestObject(tmpPiece.targetTile)){
        tmpPiece.x = tmpPiece.targetObj.x - tmpPiece.tar_mc.x;
        tmpPiece.y = tmpPiece.targetObj.y - tmpPiece.tar_mc.y;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: where in your code do you address the "tar1_mc" "tar2_mc" etc which are different than target_mc means tar_mc=/=target_mc

Comment: Always getting this error with your code:TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.

Comment: Perhaps it would be good if you clarified what all those objects are.   What is the purpose of `tarx_mc`.   What line of code does the error point to?

Comment: targetx_mc is a movieclip on my stage/scene. tarx_mc is a movieclip inside a puzzle piece. basicly target_mc and tarx_mc are both square formed movieclips which should snap together. The error points to somewhere inside my code but not a specific place: at puzzle_fla::MainTimeline/frame1().

Comment: i uploaded 3 imgs where you can see: pieces_mc, target_mc and tar_mc: http://imgur.com/a/fmkVZ and i checked it all my white squars have the right name: target1_mc, target2_mc, target3_mc and so on.

Comment: rename `tagertObj` to `targetTile`  I apparantly forgot what I had called it by the time I got the end of my answer...

Comment: ok works perfectly now. any idea how to add a fuction where the piece gets set back to its position if its not the right place? I can ask a new question if you want

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < puzzleArray.length; i++)
{
    if(puzzleArray[i].hitTestObject(puzzleArray[i]._target))
    {
        puzzleArray[i].x = puzzleArray[i]._xGoal;
        puzzleArray[i].y = puzzleArray[i]._yGoal;
    }
}
```

Obviously you'll need to add a couple of properties to the puzzle piece objects (`_xGoal`, `_yGoal`,`_target`) and you can do that however you'd like.  You could probably use a loop, but only if there is some sort of order to them.  If they are not of equal size and in a grid, then you'll have to obviously just manually type these in.

If they are in a grid and each piece is equal size, let me know if you need help with creating those properties in a loop.

Comment: they are in a grid and each piece is equal size. can you tell me how to create a loop with the right properties?

Comment: I'll try to get to it at my late lunch